# QGIS - Convert a text field to a clickable hyperlink, hotlink, or URL?

Tags: qgis, convert, url

Just starting out learning QGIS, on version 3.6.3 Windows 64 bit.

I have imported some data into QGIS. When I click the parcel I would like for the "WIC" field attribute to be a clickable hyperlink, hotlink, or URL. It is a link to a simple text file.

How can I do this? Here a screenshot below :

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Chris Webster, if my Answer resolve your question, I like it if you give the check of my answer how the solution for your question. if important to my receive this feedback. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option: Go to the layer properties>attributes form and change the field widget type to attachment, scroll down the box and tick the "use a hyperlink to the document path".

[image]

When you use the identify features tool you will then see a hyperlink e.g.

[image]

Comment: Thanks everyone. I think those solutions will do the job!

Answer (score 7):

Go to properties of the layer with right click and properties

This, show you a properties of the layer, find the option Actions and select the green plus

[image]

This will show us a wizard to configure the action, in Type: select Open and in Description write, “Open file” for example. in the Action text put: [%”name_of_the_field_have_the_url”%], like this:

[image]

Press ok and ok.

Finally, select this icon

[image]

[image]

The option **open Url** and click in your layer to see the field you linked.

[image]